# referencing ID of SQL row in VB.NET to Update the selected row on a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-update

Hoping someone can provide some suggestions for this, hopefully an easy fix. There are 2 issues:

1. I have a data grid view in VB.NET and the bit I'm stuck as is when you click on the row to update it, then with the code I have I can't seem to reference the existing Unique ID from the SQL table in my code to update it, instead I get the updated row as a new row with a new ID and the updated data.

Through experimenting I have used a new Guid.NewGuid but as I said I'm unsure how to reference the actual ID from the SQL database to update that row.

The code that is called from the update button is as follows:

```
Private Sub UpdateDataToQuery()

    Dim MyCmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim myTable As New DataTable()
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty

    'Reference the Opened connection from other conn call and load update query

    myConn.Open()
    MyCmd.Connection = myConn
    MyCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    sSQL = "UPDATE MySQlTable1 set myTable.Columns(1).ColumnName = @InputDate, 
myTable.Columns(2).ColumnName = @staffMember, myTable.Columns(3).ColumnName = @Band, 
myTable.Columns(4).ColumnName = @Defecit, myTable.Columns(5).ColumnName = @Reason, 
myTable.Columns(6).ColumnName = @ward, myTable.Columns(7).ColumnName = @AuthoriserName5, 
myTable.Columns(8).ColumnName = @AuthoriserName6 WHERE OT_ID = @guidValue"



    MyCmd.CommandText = sSQL
    da.SelectCommand = MyCmd
    da.Fill(myTable) **<<<< Error here Incorrect syntax near '.'**

    'Parameters for update query

    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guidValue", Guid.NewGuid)
    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InputDate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffMember", ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem))
    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ward", ComboBox2.GetItemText(ComboBox2.SelectedItem))
    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Defecit", ComboBox3.GetItemText(ComboBox3.SelectedItem))
    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", ComboBox4.GetItemText(ComboBox4.SelectedItem))
    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Band", ComboBox5.GetItemText(ComboBox5.SelectedItem))
    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthoriserName5", ComboBox6.GetItemText(ComboBox6.SelectedItem))
    MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthoriserName6", ComboBox7.GetItemText(ComboBox7.SelectedItem))

    MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub
```

2. I'm also now getting an error for *incorrect syntax near '.'* which never happened before, I don't know what caused it. I suspect some issue with the SQL Statement as I originally had it with breaklines, so I could see it on code window, then it raised incorect syntax near '&'. I removed those and put the code in one line and it now gives the other error.

So, as I said it did execute before without error, now it is getting the above error at da.fill(MyTable)  any pointers for the now apparent error (Point 2) would be helpful too.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `da.SelectCommand = MyCmd` But MyCmd in not a Select command. It is an Update command. A Select command would start with the word "Select". You wouldn't be filling a DataSet/DataTable with an Update command.

Comment: In your Update string you are referring to variables. The compiler won't know that. It only sees the characters of a string. You need to use String.Format or an interpolated string.

Comment: Please don't use `.AddWithValue` See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: You just created your DataTable. It won't have any columns or column names.

Comment: To update a specific record you would need the primary key for that record. Providing a new GUID will not locate a specific record in the database.